# bash - find the differed string in column of file

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

I have a file input.txt, in bash using sed,awk or shell script how can I get the only differed string in a column amount all?

For example:

```
# cat input.txt
878933fa4965c31c88ee8696a1a5838f  abc xyz
878933fa4965c31c88ee8696a1a5838f  abc xyz
878933fa4965c31c88ee8696a1a5838f  abc xyz
878933fa4965c31c88ee8696a1a5838f  abc xyz
878933fa4965c31c88ee8696a1a5838f  abc xyz
878933fa4965c31c88ee8696a1a5838f  abc xyz
878933fa4965c31c88ee8696a1axxxxx  abc xyz
878933fa4965c31c88ee8696a1a5838f  abc xyz
878933fa4965c31c88ee8696a1a5838f  abc xyz
878933fayyyyyy1c88ee8696a1a5838f  abc xyz
878933fa4965c31c88ee8696a1a5838f  abc xyz
878933fa4965c31c88ee8696a1a5838f  abc xyz
```

I want to pick and display only "878933fa4965c31c88ee8696a1axxxxx" and "878933fayyyyyy1c88ee8696a1a5838f"

Comment: Clarify **why** that would be the expected output and in particular state why `878933fa4965c31c88ee8696a1a5838f` isn't included in the output.

Comment: Its a md5sum encode of a file. I want to pick a file's md5sum if one or two file code is different from amount total of 15 or so. Or to find out of sync files.

Comment: Thanks guys for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{print $1}' <file> |uniq -u
awk '{print $4}' <file> |uniq -u
```

Answer (score 0):

In pure Bash:

```
declare -A lines
while read col1 line ; do lines["$col1"]="$col1 $line" ; done < input.txt
for i in ${!lines[@]} ; do echo "$i" ; done
```

First we declare the **lines** variable as an associative array.  Then we read them all in a while loop. Then for each key (the first column) we list the lines.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is kinda vague but **maybe** you're trying to print the $1 values that appear only once and if so this would do that:

```
$ awk '{cnt[$1]++} END{for (i in cnt) if (cnt[i]==1) print i}' file
878933fayyyyyy1c88ee8696a1a5838f
878933fa4965c31c88ee8696a1axxxxx
```

Answer (score 0):

`uniq -c` will give you a count, so if you mean only the entries of one single entry you can do:

```
cut -d " " -f 1 file | sort | uniq -c | awk '$1==1{print $2}'
```

Or in `perl`:

```
perl -lane '$seen{$F[0]}++; END{for (%seen){ print if  $seen{$_}==1}}' file
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
cat input.txt | uniq -u | awk '{print $1}'
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* it addresses the question.  Without that, your answer has much less educational value - remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.  In particular, whey do you need to use `cat` instead of having `uniq` read directly from the file?